# Making VMware player fullscreen in windows?

Tags: vmware-player

How can I make VMware player run the VM in full screen in windows? I'm using VMware Player 4.0.2.

Comment: @wizlog please don't edit questions in such a way that you change the original meaning. The user had asked how to put it into _fullscreen_, and you changed it to say _maximized_, which led to some answers below that misinterpreted that.

Comment: @user Apologies, I (mistakenly) thought the only difference was the word choice, not the meaning of the question.

Comment: @nhinkle Now I realize how easy it is to change the meaning of the question, and will be more careful going forward.

Comment: @Rajat what is the guest os?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the maximize button on the top right hand side of the window:

[image]

You'll also need VMWare Tools installed on the guest in order to have the VM resize the desktop accordingly.

Comment: that doesn't make it fullscreen & it only makes use of half of screen & the rest area is just black..

Comment: @user It works on my machine. Are you sure you have VMWare Tools installed on the VM?

Answer (score 9):

You can use Ctrl-Alt-Enter shortcut.
If you have vmware tools in guest installed it will change screen resolution to match one of host.

Comment: If only it did... mine used to do that, after installing and then removing VMWare tools it's stuck in a resolution and refuses to fullscreen / maximise or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem as you did. Here is my solution:

I installed Ubuntu in the VMware player. You just right click, and click "Change Desktop Background", and click "all setting" at upper left corner. Click "Displays" and change the resolution to 2560 by 1600.

Hope this solves your problem. Thanks

Comment: Does this work if Windows (or any other OS) is installed on the VM? Does the resolution have to be 2560x1600, or can it be the max resolution of the monitor?

Answer (score 1):

If the above does not work (my VMWare Workstation 12 does not have this under "change desktop background"), try Display (either on desktop or in menu)

VMWare menu: System/Preferences/Display

change Resolution to 1280 x 800 or more, hit Apply, Keep, Close
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have any of these menus :/

Answer (score 1):

I will post here the solution for Ubuntu guest os installed on windows

In the Ubuntu, get terminal (**Ctrl** + **Alt** + **T**)
run below command and press **Y** then **Enter**

```
sudo apt install open-vm-tools
```

After installation completed run below command in the terminal.

```
sudo apt install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

after installation restarts the vm. Then press **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **Enter** to go full screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to play a Windows XP virtual machine on Windows 10.  I somewhat solved it by going to the control panel, then display, then changing the settings.  I'm using 1440x900 which shows a little black on the sides and requires me to scroll down to see the bottom, but it's better than looking at a very small VM screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just got my problem solved.

1. In menu bar, goto VM
2. Search for install VMware tools and click on it
3. A dvd file with .exe will be downloaded.
4. Run the file
5. In the installation settings click on Typical installation.
6. Once installation completes, reboot the VM and you will get the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to change resolution in hope of real full screen, it prompted to install VM Tools which I selected (I otherwise couldn't find this option and what I was looking for it).

It still didn't install but there was instructions on screen (if installation didn't begin), go to file explorer, D:\ drive and run setup.exe, this install the tools.

Basically Window button + R and type d:\setup.exe or just go to the file explorer and run it.

Answer (score -1):

It works by changing resolution of monitor.
Keep monitor resolution as your system configuration

Comment: What works by changing monitor resolution?  What do you mean by "keep monitor resolution as your system configuration"?  How is this a solution to the question?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please be aware you have posted an answer to a question that is very old and has an accepted answer. Although there is nothing wrong with doing so, just be aware you may not get a response.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem as you did. Here is my solution:

1. Edit>Preferences
2. Click "display" on left menu
3. in the middle part, select "stretch guest"
4. return to your virtual OS and click on "Full-Screen"